# Remove specific object from list (c++)

Tags: c++, list, object, element

I want to remove a specific object from my list `wielrennerslist` but some how is giving errors while compiling.

```
cout << "Wielrenner" << endl;

list<Wielrenner> wielrennerslist = wielerploegOB.getWielrennersList();
cout << "Welke wielrenner wil je verwijderen?" << endl;

// Alle objecten afprinten in de lijst
for (list<Wielrenner>::iterator it = wielrennerslist.begin(); it != wielrennerslist.end(); it++) {
    Wielrenner wielrennerOB = *it;
    cout << teller << " - " << wielrennerOB.getVoornaam() << " " << wielrennerOB.getAchternaam() << endl;
    teller++;
}
cin >> inputID;

// Naar het object gaan
int N = inputID; /* index of the element you want to retrieve */
if (wielrennerslist.size() > N) {
    list<Wielrenner>::iterator iter = wielrennerslist.begin();
    std::advance(iter, N);

    // 'it' points to the element at index 'N'
    Wielrenner* wielrennerOB2;
    wielrennerOB2 = &*iter;

    wielrennerslist.remove(*wielrennerOB2); // something wrong with this?

    wielerploegOB.setWielrennerList(wielrennerslist);
}//if
```

Comment: What are the errors you get? And could you please take care to properly indent your code here? 4 spaces per level would do the trick. That makes it easier for us to read.

Comment: Since you already have an iterator pointing to the element to be removed, why don't you use the list's [erase()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/erase/) function?

Comment: I don't think `list::remove` does what you think it does here. I think you really want to use `list::erase`, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the iterator and [std::list::erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase) to remove the element in question like this:

```
wielrennerslist.erase(iter);
```

Otherwise, the remove method should be used like this:

```
wielrennerslist.remove(*iter);
```

But this method doesn't do what I think you want to do. It will remove **all** elements that are equal to the value of the element at position `N`. But if this is what you want, then you need to have an equality comparison for `Wielrenner` objects. See [std::list::remove](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/remove).